# Compare 2 .txt after installing software in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to write a code for my school which compares 2 .txt files after installing a software. It should be NOT displaying on the first .txt the x software I have installed, but in the 2nd it should. I wrote this but I can't manage to compare them as the x software is both missing on either .txt files.
How can I get this to work?

```
$array1 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
          sort -Property installdate -Descending |
          Format-Table DisplayName, @{Name="InstallDate"; Expression={([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)).ToShortDateString()}}
$array2 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
          sort -Property installdate -Descending |
          Format-Table DisplayName, @{Name="InstallDate"; Expression={([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', $null)).ToShortDateString()}}

$array1 | Export-Clixml C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test.txt

$counter = 0

Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

$array2 | Export-Clixml C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test_dif.txt

#Compare-object -ReferenceObject (Import-Clixml C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test.txt) -DifferenceObject ($array2)     
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test_dif.txt)
```

Comment: You assign the same value to `$array1` and `$array2`. Why would you expect any differences to show up? Where would they supposedly come from? Also, exporting arrays as XML files and re-importing them as plain text files is not going to help with anything. Plus, you shouldn't use `Format-Table` unless you're displaying data to a user.

Answer (score 0):

Your Script will work just fine for applications that are either x32 on a x32 version or windows or x64 on a x64 version of windows.

If the application is x32 on a x64 version of windows, the application will be listed in the key below.

x32 Programs on x64 Windows OS:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

Try doing a compare with the new key and see if you application is there.

I would also format the output as text with "out-file" rather than "export-Clixml" because its much easier to compare with out all that extra formatting.  The text document is 21 times smaller than the same XML formatted file.

```
$array1 | export-Clixml C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test.txt
$array1 | out-file C:\Users\Qendrim\Desktop\lb02_test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is actually quite a simple one. When you execute:

```
$array2 = Get-ItemProperty 
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
          sort -Property installdate -Descending |
          Format-Table DisplayName, @{Name="InstallDate"; Expression=
{([DateTime]::ParseExact($_.InstallDate, 'yyyyMMdd', 
$null)).ToShortDateString()}}
```

It will save the data to that variable then and there. When you export to the file after the sleep period, you're exporting the data you saved earlier, not the data how it is after the sleep period.

The fix is simple, assuming that you are installing/uninstalling the software during the sleep period. All you need to move those lines down to be under "Start-Sleep 10".

This combined with DonBennettJr's suggestion of using "Out-File" instead of "Export-Clixml" should get you on the right track.